# SwipeListView in ExpandableListView, is it possible?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I am using https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview to create a list view with swipeable items. I am wondering is it possible to apply this to `ExpandableListView` so that child elements can be swiped.

Comment: i guess its possible, give it a try though and let us know :-/

Comment: Have you ever been able to do this? I'm having the same problem (need swipe on childs of ExpandableListView)

Comment: Switched to this library https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout, but the solution turned out to be somewhat hacky. I would recommend you go some other way if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to make it work (at least for me). Here's a list of the steps that I took:

- Copy SwipeListView class and rename to ExpandableSwipeListView.
- Make it extend from ExpandableListView.
- Copy SwipeListViewTouchListener class and rename to ExpandableSwipeListViewTouchListener
- Change SwipeListViewTouchListener calls inside ExpandableSwipeListView to ExpandableSwipeListViewTouchListener.
- Change SwipeListView calls inside SwipeListViewTouchListener to ExpandableSwipeListView.
- Change method resetItems of ExpandableSwipeListViewTouchListener to this:

-

```
/**
 * Adds new items when adapter is modified
 */
public void resetItems() {
    ExpandableListAdapter adp=swipeListView.getExpandableListAdapter();
    if (adp != null) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<adp.getGroupCount();i++){
            //Add the total children and the group itself.
            count+=adp.getChildrenCount(i) + 1;
        }
        for (int i = opened.size(); i <= count; i++) {
            opened.add(false);
            openedRight.add(false);
            checked.add(false);
        }
    }
}
```

- Create expandableswipelistview__attrs.xml on res/values with teh following:

  ```
  <declare-styleable name="ExpandableSwipeListView">
      <attr name="swipeOpenOnLongPress"/>
      <attr name="swipeAnimationTime"/>
      <attr name="swipeOffsetLeft"/>
      <attr name="swipeOffsetRight"/>
      <attr name="swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList"/>
      <attr name="swipeFrontView"/>
      <attr name="swipeBackView"/>
      <attr name="swipeGroupView" format="reference"/>
      <attr name="swipeMode"/>
      <attr name="swipeActionLeft"/>
      <attr name="swipeActionRight"/>
      <attr name="swipeDrawableChecked"/>
      <attr name="swipeDrawableUnchecked"/>
  </declare-styleable>
  ```
- Add tag swipe:swipeGroupView to the declaration of your ExpandableSwipeListView on the layout. Example:

-

```
swipe:swipeGroupView="@+id/group"
```

- The id should be something unique and that must be declared on the layout of your groups.
- On init method of ExpandableSwipeListView change all styleables to "ExpandableSwipeListView_..." and on "obtainStyledAttributes" set it to R.styleable.ExpandableSwipeListView.
- Add swipeGroupView like swipeFrontView on the init method and pass it to ExpandableSwipeListViewTouchListener constructor.
- On ExpandableSwipeListViewTouchListener add the following code after "if (allowSwipe && rect.contains(x, y)) {":

-

```
//verify if it is a group:
if (child.findViewById(swipeGroupView)!=null){
    return false;
}
```

- Add these methods to ExpandableSwipeListView. They are helpful to make dismiss callbacks and other things:

-

```
/**
 * Returns the group and child positions for a child element.
 * This values are passed inside an array of dimension 2 where the index 0 is the group position and the index 1 is the child position.
 * @param general_position used on the list (compatible with getChildAt)
 * @return int[2] 0 => group position; 1 => child position
 */
public int[] getGroupAndChildPositions(int general_position){
    //get group and child ids
    int groupPosition=0;
    int childPosition=0;
    int helper=general_position;
    for (int i=0;i<getExpandableListAdapter().getGroupCount();i++){
        if (helper-getExpandableListAdapter().getChildrenCount(i)-1<=0){
            groupPosition=i;
            childPosition=helper-1;
            break;
        } else {
            helper-=getExpandableListAdapter().getChildrenCount(i)+1;
        }
    }
    return new int[]{groupPosition,childPosition};
}

/**
 * Returns the general position of an element on the list (used by getChildAt)
 * @param groupPosition
 * @param childPosition
 * @return the position on the list
 */
public int getGeneralPosition(int groupPosition, int childPosition){
    int position=0;
    for (int i=0;i<=groupPosition;i++){
        if (i<groupPosition)
            position+=getExpandableListAdapter().getChildrenCount(i)+1;
        else{
            position+=childPosition+1;
        }
    }
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Hello, can you give more informations? I have the same problem but I don't succed to implemente your solution. The radle build give my the error : `Error:In <declare-styleable> ExpandableSwipeListView, unable to find attribute swipeActionLeft`

Comment: do you have any github repository for the same

Comment: Ok, I found the code and added it to there: [https://github.com/reyalpsirc/ExpandableSwipeListView](https://github.com/reyalpsirc/ExpandableSwipeListView)